# Web page access in iPhone Application

Tags: iphone, sdk3.0

Is there any way for accessing the web page in iPhone application, without address bar and bookmark bar. Application load the web page whose address is prefix in coding.

Comment: looks like you want to make a browser in iPhone, which is forbidden by iPhone SDK Agreement... you can't replace Mobile Safari.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please consider [UIWebView](http://developer.apple.com/iPhone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIWebView_Class/index.html) for all your web page display needs (whether accessing real remote sites, or displaying HTML embedded in your application. There are lots of good samples on the Apple [iPhone Dev Center](http://developer.apple.com/iPhone/), and lots of [related questions here on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/uiwebview).